# Permission for Uploading file

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, permissions

My hosting server does not allow to create folder/directory above `WWW` so my folder structure is

```
www.site.com  
   img  
   script
```

I've placed javascript in the script folder, and user on the site should be able to upload images on the `img` folder.
What permission should i use for those 2 directory ?

I'm new to Linux, so dont have knowledge on setting the necessary permission. On my Ubuntu if i set the permission to 777, only then i can upload images. Else it shows permission denied.

Comment: Some answer shows on SO to use 777, 766 . So I'm confused. Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

766 is useless for a folder. A folder that does not have the x-bit cannot be entered at all. so it's pretty much like 700.

If you need 777 or 770 (or 775) depends on the setup of the server. If you are in the same group as the webserver, 770 or 775 will suffice. Otherwise you'll need 777.

Comment: +1, but giving 777 means user can do what ever they want, they can upload malicious file execute them or so ...

Comment: That's bs. Only people with access to the server can write to the folder ("world"-writable refers to "all users on the system"). If you are on shared hosting the ISP should have a setup where other customers are prevented from accessing your folders at all or such wide permissions are not necessary (unfortunately they *are* necessary on most webspace hosts)

Answer (score 2):

> ps aux

to see which user apache process belongs to.
After that,

> chown apacheusername directory -R
>
> chmod 744 directory -R

that should give access to that directory for apache, but will only let any other user to see the directory. If you dont want that directory to be seen, just set to 700.